# Passing an anonymous type as T

Tags: c#, entity-framework, anonymous-types

In the Entity Framework you can run and bind custom queries on-the-fly like so...

```
protected class NitrogenMoisutreContainer
{
    public double MinN { get; set; }
    public double MaxN { get; set; }
    public double MinM { get; set; }
    public double MaxM { get; set; }
}

// ...

var q = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<NitrogenMoisutreContainer>(@"SELECT MAX(NitrogenBalance) as MaxN, MIN(NitrogenBalance) as MinN, MAX(FCWaterPercent) as MaxM, MIN(FCWaterPercent) as MinM
                                                                    FROM agZoneProjectionGrowthStages
                                                                    WHERE NitrogenBalance > 0 AND FCWaterPercent > 0").First();
```

The problem is that, to me, this feels messy. I had to create this class for one query and **I will never use it again for anything else**. The results are used exactly one line down from where it is executed.

Is there a way I can return an anonymous type? Even if I had to declare it first, like this...

```
var anonItem = new {
    MinN = 0d,
    MaxN = 0d,
    MinM = 0d,
    MaxM = 0d
};

var q = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<anonItem.GetType()>("...");
```

I just can't figure out how to pass in my anonymous type's `Type` as `T`. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as generics are determined at compile time.

Comment: @Matthew It's *possible*, although it'd be hacky.  As to whether there's a *good* approach, that I don't know.

Comment: @Matthew And the answer posted was even the one that I was debating posting myself.  Now we're both freaked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that, to me, this feels messy. I had to create this class for one query and **I will never use it again for anything else**. The results are used exactly one line down from where it is executed.

I don't see this as a problem.

> Is there a way I can return an anonymous type?

You could create a [tuple](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple) instead.

Comment: Any suggestions for best practices on where these one-off sort of proxy classes should be stored? I hate just having them dangling around.

Comment: @jocull: I usually just create them as private inner classes to restrict the accessibility and communicate the intentionally limited applicability. // Depending on your coding style, you could declare them near the method where they are used, at the end of the file, or even grouped together within their own #region.

Comment: Tuples do not work! I started off with Tuples and quickly found out {"The result type 'System.Tuple`2[System.Int32,System.String]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor."}. Use a concrete class appears to be the proven way to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done if you set it up so the type can be inferred.  E.g.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetObjects<T>(T exampleItem, string sqlQuery) { ... }
var q = GetObjects(anonItem, @"");
```

I think this is a bit hackish, and I'd suggest trying another approach, like actually making the named class or using a tuple.

Comment: I'm with you on that... having the method to force the compiler to deal with it does feel a bit hackish.

Comment: I think that tuples are a no-go. ``The result type 'System.Tuple`4[System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.``

Comment: You'll actually get similar errors with an anon type by inference too... ``The result type '<>f__AnonymousType7`4[System.Double,System.Double,System.Double,System.Double]' may not be abstract and must include a default constructor.`` Any suggestions for best practices on where these one-off sort of proxy classes should be stored? I hate just having them dangling around.